# Adding cardholder name in Stripe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

So the problem I am facing is this. Here I have created PaymentForm with Stripe. So when I am not entering the input value of CardHolder name, and when I press the Purchase button it should display the  `<h1>Please enter your cardholder name</h1>`  but it is not doing it. I just want to create a test of  Cardholder name, I know the documentation of Stripe is showing real approaches. Where could the error be located?

```
Payment form

import React,{useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from"@stripe/react-stripe-js"
import { CartContext } from '../../context/cart'

import {  useHistory, Link } from "react-router-dom";



const PaymentForm = () => {
  const { total} = useContext(CartContext)
  const {cart, cartItems}= useContext(CartContext)
  const history = useHistory()
  const {clearCart} = useContext(CartContext)
  const [nameError, setNameError]=useState(null)
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState('');
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState('');
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  useEffect(() => {
    // Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
    window
      .fetch("http://localhost:5000/create-payment-intent", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({items: [{cart}]})
      })
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        setClientSecret(data.clientSecret);
      });
  }, [cart]);
  const cardStyle = {
    style: {
      base: {
        color: "#32325d",
        fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
        fontSize: "16px",
        "::placeholder": {
          color: "#32325d"
        }
      },
      invalid: {
        color: "#fa755a",
        iconColor: "#fa755a"
      }
    }
  };
  const handleChange = async (event) => {
    setDisabled(event.empty);
    setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");
  };
  const handleChangeInput = async (event) => {
    setDisabled(event.empty);
    setNameError(event.nameError ? event.nameError.message : "");
    setName(event.target.value)
  };

  const handleSubmit = async ev => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);
    const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
      }
    });

   
    if (payload.error) {
      setError(`Payment failed ${payload.error.message}`);
      setProcessing(false);
    } else {
      setNameError(null)
      setError(null);     
      setProcessing(false);
      setSucceeded(true)
      clearCart()
    }
  };  
  useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {  
    if(succeeded){
      history.push('/')
    }
    }, 3000);
  },[history, succeeded])
 
console.log(name)
 
  return (
    <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h2>Checkout</h2>
      <div className='payment__cont'>
       <label>Cardholder Name </label>
       <input 
        placeholder='Please enter your Cardholder name'
        type="text"
        id="name"
        value={name}
        onChange={handleChangeInput}
         />
      </div>
      <div className="stripe-input">
          <label htmlFor="card-element">
            Credit or Debit Card
            </label>
          <p className="stripe-info">
            Test using this credit card : <span>4242 4242 4242 4242</span>
            <br />
            enter any 5 digits for the zip code
            <br />
            enter any 3 digits for the CVC
          </p>
        </div>
      <CardElement id="card-element" options={cardStyle} onChange={handleChange} />
      <div className='review__order'>
      <h2>Review Order</h2>
      <h4>Total amount to pay ${total}</h4>
      <h4>Total amount of items {cartItems}</h4>
      <button
        className='purchase__button'
        disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}
        id="submit"
      >     
        <span id="button-text">
          {processing ? (
            <div className="spinner" id="spinner"></div>
          ) : (
            "Complete purchase"
          )}
        </span>
      </button>
      <button className='edit__button'onClick={()=> {history.push('/cart')}}>Edit Items</button>
      </div>
      {error && (
        <div className="card-error" role="alert">
          {error}
        </div>
      )}

       {nameError && (
        <div className="card-error" role="alert">
          <h1>Please enter yor card holder name</h1>
        </div>
      )}
      <p className={succeeded  ? "result-message" : "result-message hidden"}>
        Payment succeeded        
          {''}
          <h1>Redirecting you yo the home</h1>
      </p>
  
    </form>
  );
}



export default PaymentForm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You still need to validate your `name` input yourself. Stripe doesn't do that for you

Your `handleChangeInput` handler only fires when you write to your `name` input, and you're treating the event as if it's fired from a Stripe component, but it's not, so try this:

```
  // Validates name input only
  const handleChangeInput = async (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;

    // Disable when value is empty
    setDisabled(!value); 

    // Set the error if value is empty
    setNameError(value ? "" : "Please enter a name");

    // Update form value
    setName(value)
  };
```

Comment: It's still  not doing it.

Comment: should I add an error message in the handleSubmit

Comment: yes you should also add a check for `name` existing in `handleSubmit()` and if it is `""` then you should present the error by setting `setNameError` state

Comment: As mentioned earlier, `name` isn't something Stripe requires in `confirmCardPayment()` but is instead something your code is collecting, so your code needs to check for it. And then also pass it in the `billing_details` hash on `confirmCardPayment()` as shown here: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment

Comment: @hmunoz If it is not to much to ask, can you put handleSubmit() logic as an answer.

Comment: I can't write the full code here but you basically just need an `if (name.length > 0)` type check there, and confirm the PaymentIntent if that check is met (i.e. there is a non zero length name set). If the check isn't met, then in the `else` block you set `setErrorName`

Comment: @hmunoz confirm the payment?

Comment: by "confirm the payment" I mean the line of code where you call `stripe.confirmCardPayment()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do is possible with Stripe elements as cardholder name isn't actually part of it. You'll need to handle it yourself.

An alternative way of ensuring the name field is entered prior to the card element being pressed would be to force input into cardholder name field before displaying/enabling the Stripe Card Element. This way you can be more certain the the name has been entered (and then you can do what you like with it) before the card element is pressed. You could do this a lot of ways, but for example in your render:

```
{name.length >= 10 ? ( //Check length of name
<CardElement id="card-element" options={cardStyle} onChange={handleChange} />
) : (
   <span>Please enter your cardholder name.</span> // do nothing if check not passed  
)}
```

This is a really simple example but it checks the length of name and then if greater than or equals ten characters makes the card element visible. You could instead use your handleChangeInput to set a boolean state (true or false) on button press or something; it would be better to make this more robust.

edit: some clarifications.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWhereTheTimeGoesI just want to figure out how should I display the error message when the input value is empty or less than 10 characters when the Purchase button is pressed

Comment: The card element in this solution doesn't show until that condition is achieved; the error message displays as default and the card element only appears once the error is corrected. I use this conditional rendering method myself in production and its a more clear sequential flow for the customer.  It is hard and not advisable to interfere with the CardElement as it's designed to passthrough the necessary data to stripe without you having to handle it (for PCI/DSS compliance). In your example, you want to know if its been pressed prior to stripes response.

Comment: So in you example, I have to meet the first condition or Enter cardholder name, and then Element appears

Comment: Yes. It uses inline conditional rendering (https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to hide card element until name.length >= 10, and display a message until then. So long as your "name" state is being set on input, of course ;)